# SharePoint 2013 File Not Found Missing Page Layout

Tags: sharepoint, page-layout

How do I detach a page layout from a page and attach a different one?  Is there a powershell command.  SharePoint Designer is throwing an error.

I deployed a new set of master pages and page layouts and removed my old ones.  I missed detaching a couple pages from the page layouts and now when I try to open those pages I'm getting a File Not Found.  I've recovered the old page layouts and I still cannot open the pages.  I tried detaching the page layout in SharePoint Designer but it's throwing an error "operation is not valid due to the state of the object."

Comment: You can change the page layout directly by Editing the page in browser , why do you want to detach ..? , Question is not clear..... How could you remove old page layouts , while it is already atached to some pages..?

Comment: I can't edit the page in the browser.  When I do I get a file not found message.  The page that is missing is the layout page, so I need to detach the layout page so I can edit it in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
I had to download the page and edit the properties in a text editor and then upload the file.  DO NOT DELETE THE FILE on the SharePoint site and re-add.  It but be copied over the original.

Steps to fix this issue.
Download the SharePoint Page.
Navigate to the location of the new page layout
Take note of the following:
 1) Name 
 2) Title
 3) ContentTypeId (IN THE URL).

Edit the Page in text editor - use the values from above without the "***" below.
Replace xxx.xxx.com with your site.
    |mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string"|***ContentTypeId***|/mso:ContentTypeId|
    |mso:PublishingPageLayoutName msdt:dt="string"|***Name***|/mso:PublishingPageLayoutName|
    |mso:PublishingPageLayout msdt:dt="string"|https://xxx.xxx.com/_catalogs/masterpage/***Name***, ***Title***|/mso:PublishingPageLayout|
Upload the Page to the same location as the original.